# Evaluate the continuity of this function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Ok so after countless hours looking at video about epsilon-delta, I still can't understand it. I am asked to evaluate the continuity of this function using epsilon-delta.

$$f(x,y) = \begin{Bmatrix}
\dfrac{5x^3+7y^4+6y^3-x^2y}{x^2+y^2} &if (x,y)\neq 0) \\0 
 &if (x,y)=0)
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Does f is continuous at (0,0)? Explain

Thank you

Comment: You should start with easier example first if you're still not comfortable with $\delta - \epsilon$ approach. The thing require some time to get used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$; then for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ we have
$$
\bigg|
\frac{5x^{3} + 7y^{4} + 6y^{3} - x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\bigg|
\leq
\frac{5|x^{3}| + 7y^{4} + 6|y^{3}| + |x^{2}y|}{x^{2}+y^{2}}.
$$
If $|x| \leq |y| \leq 1$, then
$$
\frac{5|x^{3}| + 7y^{4} + 6|y^{3}| + |x^{2}y|}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\leq
\frac{7y^{4} + 12|y^{3}|}{2x^{2}} 
\leq
\frac{19|y^{3}|}{2x^{2}} \leq \frac{19}{2}|y|,
$$
which is $< \varepsilon$ if in addition we have $|y| < 2\varepsilon/19$; therefore, if $|x| \leq |y| < \min \{ 1, 2\varepsilon/19 \}$, then the absolute value of the value of the map at $(x,y)$ can be made $< \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates:
\begin{align*}
\biggl\lvert\frac{5x^3+7y^4+6y^3-x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\biggr\rvert&=\frac{\bigl\lvert5r^3\cos^3\theta+7r^4\sin^4\theta+6r^3\sin^3\theta-r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\bigr\rvert}{r^2}\\
&=r\bigl\lvert5\cos^3\theta+7r\sin^4\theta+6\sin^3\theta-\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\bigr\rvert\\
&\le r(5+7+6+1)=19r,
\end{align*}
if we suppose $r\le 1$. From there it is easy to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument.